# Not able to add Users to Site Collection in SharePoint 2013

Tags: site-collection, user

I am having big issues in adding users to a site collection to giving them access.

Let me describe to you my problem:

1. I have created a site collection and can set the site collection administrators.
2. To even allow the site administrators access I have to set Everyone in the User Policy in Managed Web Application. If I change this, everyone is not able to access the site. Why it is this way, I do not know.
3. User Profile Synchronization Service is set to Active Directory Import and ALL Services are running. I have left User Properties to default and thus deliberately have not changed them
4. Leaving access to Everyone through User Policy, I can then log on to the site. Going to site settings, and then to Site Permissions, searching for a user to add to the site, returns nothing. There are no users coming up.
5. However, in Central Administration I can see ALL my users from Active Directory.

So, can someone please if they can answer me the following questions:

1. How do I ensure that I can see any user imported into SharePoint 2013 are visible in any Site Collection?
2. How do I ensure that a Site Collection Administrator set during Site Collection creation can get access without having to set User Policy to Everyone, or is this the way?

Comment: This is through Central Administration

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is not a programming question.

It might be useful to enable verbose level SharePoint ULS in central admin and see what authentication error or relevant info it catches when a AD user attempts to access the site you referred.

Comment: This is not the issue. The problem is that I cannot ADD users to the site in order for them to access the site in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that there is no dependency between the UPS and security. You do not need a sync before you can add users.

What happens when you can't access? Do you get a 401 or a SharePoint message to say you don't have access?

I assume you have a farm account? Can it access the site collections after you have created them? Can you access the web objects via powershell? If so Can you test this:

```
$web = Get-SpWeb http://spsite
$web.ensureuser("domain\user")
```

Does the above throw an exception or return a userlogin and displayname?